# JQuery/Globalize: Method for finding best matching locale?

Tags: javascript-globalize

As an example I have loaded following locales:

- en
- de
- de-CH

*As code:* `Globalize.load( require('cldr-data').entireMainFor('en', 'de', 'de-CH'));`
When I call `const globalize = Globalize(locale);` without having set `locale` loaded I get e.g. `Error: Cannot find module './de-AT'`

This means that I have to choose one of the existing locales:

- de-CH -> choose de-CH
- de-AT -> choose de
- en-Latn-US -> choose en
- it -> choose en

Since everybody needs this piece of code I expected this to exist in the library. Could you point me to a proper implementation?

Comment: Hey Peter, I will give you a proper answer soon. For now: `de-CH` chooses `de-CH` as expected; `de-AT` should choose `de` as you say, but a bug is currently preventing it; `en-Latn-US` chooses `en` as expected. `it` won't choose `en`, it would choose `root` if loaded.

Comment: FWIW, soon = in a couple of days weeks :P

Comment: Thanks for your reply!